# Formatting Cucumber/Gherkin as HTML

Tags: html, cucumber, pandoc, gherkin

I'm trying to find a way to programmatically transform a Github markdown file to an HTML file that will correctly perform syntax highlighting of Cucumber (Gherkin) code. I'm looking mostly at Pandoc for this but am open to other tools.

The Cucumber code is in a markdown 'fenced block' like this:

````
```cucumber

(the Cucumber code)

```
````

A similar block with '```ruby' formats correctly.  After some research I learned that Pandoc uses the highlighting-kate library.  While there is no Cucumber support built into that library, there was an attempt at a solution by Torbjörn Klatt described at http://lists.kde.org/?l=kwrite-devel&m=132620977017108. I contacted the author and while he may be able to provide some guidance, he's not available to do further substantial work on it.

Anyone have any ideas how this can be solved?  (Other than 'yeah, go write it yourself' ;) )

Thanks.

Comment: just a comment, the language name is `gherkin` (github would accept that too), `cucumber` is a CLI tool who can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extract the Gherkin Text and convert to the Gherkin document format json
https://github.com/cucumber/common/blob/main/messages/jsonschema/GherkinDocument.json

Use that to render it how you want for example the this project provides a react component to display the document in nice way.
https://github.com/cucumber/common/tree/main/react/javascript

Perhaps you cou;d use this for generating auto-complete options for editing like https://dev.to/brpaz/how-to-create-your-own-auto-completion-for-json-and-yaml-files-on-vs-code-with-the-help-of-json-schema-k1i